# Django deployment with Daphne

Tags: django, nginx, redis, daphne

UPDATE:
It may be closed, remember to always check code copied from outside... The problem was with quote marks  in Daphne Service

I want to deploy my Django app (Rest API + React on frontend)  on AWS. I use nginx, gunicorn (for http handling) and daphne (for async websockets - Im using django channels for chat application). I was following [THIS](https://medium.com/@Ritiktaneja/configuring-asgi-django-application-using-daphne-and-nginx-server-59a90456fe17) tutorial.

It looks like I configured well nginx and gunicorn (page is normally loading, I can handle sync request to rest API) but I guess there are some problems with daphne and/or asgi. I use systemctl services for server. All 3 (nginx, gunicorn, daphne) statuses show 'active'. Everything works fine on my development server on local.

On deployment server when I enter website, I see in console

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://PATH_TO_WEBSOCKET
```

Is Daphne connected well with Nginx?

I use Redis for CHANNEL_LAYERS. I have installed channels-redis and redis-server on Ubuntu server. I think it works fine as I get respond

```
> redis-cli
> ping
**PONG**
```

project tree

```
.
├── frontend #react files
├── checkers #project dir
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── asgi.py
├── chat #chat app
│   ├── consumers.py
│   └── routing.py
└── checkers.sock
```

asgi.py

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'checkers.settings')
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'checkers.urls'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "checkers.routing.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

daphne service worker

```
[Unit]
Description=My Daphne Service
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=simple 
User=ams
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ams/production_app  
ExecStart=/home/ams/production_app/production_env/bin/daphne --access-log /home/ams/production_app/log/daphne-access.log -b 0.0.0.0 -p 9001 checkers.asgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx config file at /etc/nginx/sites-available/ (our websockets endpoints start with /ws/)

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server 0.0.0.0:9001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_SERVER;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ams/production_app;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ams/production_app/checkers.sock;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

}
```